# find -exec overwriting exit status

Tags: xcode, bash

I am trying to setup a custom script build phase in XCode that will allow me to validate all the json in my project.

My script is:

```
source ~/.bashrc
eval "cd '$PROJECT_DIR'"
find . -name \*.json -exec jsonlint -q {} \;
```

The problem is, if there is a failure, it goes onto the next file and eventually exits with a status 0...  I am looking for a way to make -exec stop if it encounters a non-zero status.

I thought I could possibly handle this by manually looping over the files:

```
for f in $(find . -name *.json); do ... done;
```

however, the path to these json files contains spaces, so when I try to do it this way, $f or even "$f" shows up as "/Users/me/path", "with", "spaces/123.json", rather than the actual path which would be "/Users/me/path with spaces/123.json"

Everything I've read online says "when you double quote f, it automatically takes care of escaping spaces!"-- not true in this case!

Comment: you can also use find's `-print0` which uses nulls as the inter-file separator in the output, and then use `xargs -0` to look for that null. that'd solve the space problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a while loop:

```
find . -name '*.json' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    jsonlint -q "$file" || echo "Oh oh! " 1>&2
done
```

Comment: You may also want to stop the loop on failure: `... || { echo "Oh oh! " 1>&2; break; }`. (Note that reading null-terminated data with a `read` loop like this is mostly a `bash` feature; it seems to have been added to `zsh` only fairly recently.)

Comment: I actually did: echo "JSON linter ==> $file" && jsonlint -q "$file" 1>&2 || exit 1;  and that works PERFECTLY in XCode.  If there are any problems in my json, the build fails, which is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks!!!